# Show Diff Hunk greyed out in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

Im trying to get incremental inline diff working in Sublime text 3, but Show Diff Hunk is greyed out and not working. I'm in a branch trying to diff branch to master, for reference. I've set the setting at root level:

> "git_diff_target":"master"

But its not working. Anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

This particular setting and feature don't work the way you think they do as far as the core is concerned (but see below).

The [Incremental Diff](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/incremental_diff.html) feature that's core to the editor tracks changes to your file as you make them, based on either the state of the file as it exists on disk (for files not tracked by git) or, for files tracked by git, against the version of the file in the index or at the `HEAD` of the repository; it does not calculate deltas based on arbitrary branches.

In particular, the setting in question is:

```json
    // This setting determines whether tracked Git files should be diffed
    // against the index or HEAD.
    // Valid values are "index" or "head"
    "git_diff_target": "index",
```

So your options are either to compare against the version of the file that you checked out originally to see what you changed, or the version of the file that you checked out to see what you changed, but anything you've staged for commit is not marked as different so you can work with changes that are still pending.

To get the functionality that you're after here, you need a package that alters the default functionality; an example of that is [GitGutter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter), which has amongst its [package settings](https://jisaacks.github.io/GitGutter/settings/) a `compare_against` setting:

> GitGutter compares the content of the view against the HEAD of the checked out branch by default. To change this default behaviour the `compare_against` setting can be changed to any tag, branch or commit hash git understands.